Why do the Fourier components of a piano note shift away from the harmonic series?
This comes from me answering a question about functionally modeling a piano playing a middle C note in Mathematica.
I figured the note would consist of the fundamental frequency
f0 ~ 440 × 2−9/12 Hz and a bunch of harmonic over/undertones that are integer (or 1 over an integer) multiples of the fundamental frequency.
Indeed, if we plot the absolute values of the discrete Fourier transform (this is for a short time interval near the attack of the note), we see the dominant frequencies lie on integer multiples of the fundamental frequency:

However, as we move to higher overtones, the peaks start to deviate away from integer multiples of f0. My question is what is causing this deviation? Shouldn't it just be integer multiples of the fundamental frequency vibrating on the piano string? Is this expected behavior for a piano?

This is a phenomenon called inharmonicity, in which harmonics deviate from the expected integer multiples. This is an example of the difference between ideal mathematics and the real world. Wikipedia has a good description that relates directly to piano inharmonicity:

Music harmony and intonation depends strongly on the harmonicity of tones. An ideal, homogeneous, infinitesimally thin or infinitely flexible string or column of air has exact harmonic modes of vibration.1 In any real musical instrument, the resonant body that produces the music tone—typically a string, wire, or column of air—deviates from this ideal and has some small or large amount of inharmonicity. For instance, a very thick string behaves less as an ideal string and more like a cylinder (a tube of mass), which has natural resonances that are not whole number multiples of the fundamental frequency. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inharmonicity)

Wikipedia also includes a section specifically devoted to piano inharmonicity, which discusses string thickness as the primary influence on the instrument's inharmonicity.
The Railsback curve "expresses the difference between inharmonicity-aware stretched piano tuning and theoretically correct equal-tempered tuning in which the frequencies of successive notes are related by a constant ratio, equal to the twelfth root of two." Stretched tuning is the technique of adjusting the high and low strings on a piano slightly sharp and flat, respectively, to account for their inharmonicity.

I believe (by memory) that imprecision in harmonics contributes significantly to the timbre of a particular instrument, on top of the relative amplitudes of the harmonics themselves.

@Slate I decided to look into this. Here I compare 2 reconstructions I made to the original sound (make sure to unmute the audio). The first note is the original sound, the 2nd was made by finding the true peak frequencies of the DFT near the attack of the note and fitting each peak's intensity by least squares, and the last was made by shifting the peaks to the nearest harmonic. The first reconstruction with true peak location is a little too bright, but it is much better than the harmonic-shifted fit which is (very) flat, and sounds almost guitar-like.

@ydd That makes sense. The accordion is a wonderful instrument for demonstrating this in person. An accordion with musette tuning does exactly this by definition, tuning each note both a few cents sharp and flat. (But also, if you you look at the FT of any single note played on an accordion - particularly on the bass side - you'll see a litter of sympathetic resonances that do not belong to the reed currently being played. It's hard to imagine the sound would be the same without them.)

@Slate I really like this discussion; this has got me interested in characterizing instruments with respect to their deviation from the harmonics of the base note.

Some minor comments in addition to Aaron's answer.

A piano doesn't generate "harmonic undertones" or "subharmonics". I guess the wide peak below 1 in your plot comes from the "knock" of the piano hammer. The fact you draw the spectrum for the "short time interval near the attack of the note" may emphasize this percussive component. This sound comes from the response of the whole body of the instrument, rather than just the string, and is mostly similar for different notes. It doesn't follow the pitch of the note, so it's hard to call it "harmonic". I find it the easiest to distinguish it by ear in the highest piano notes.

The peak at "20" is the 19th component, this is how much the harmonic series got stretched. I wonder if the sample came from an upright piano? Shorter strings would explain bigger deviation.

I am curious about a peak around 15.2 in your plot. It seems to be an extra component, which doesn't follow the stretched harmonic series. What could it be its origin? Is it a recording of a real piano, or some sampled instrument? Could it be some other note resonating? If I understood your data correctly, that is the note you played is a middle C. 15.2 would correspond to around 3977 Hz, which is close to the fundamental frequency of B7, second last note on a piano. Another explanation are artifact peaks from FFT, but I don't really see them in your plot, which makes me think this might be something real.





This looks correct. Here is a plot of the Fourier spectrum far (1 s) from the start of the note. It looks like the undertones are gone, and interestingly some of the intermediate overtones are missing as well


This is a grand piano.


Although I don't know what causes the 15.2 peak, If we look still close, but not immediately after,  (0.3 s) to the start of the note we see the 15.2 peak vanishes, (but the undertones are still present, although less intense)... cont'd



... So maybe the 15.2 peak has something to do with the percussive part of the hammer?

@ydd I really don't know. But a narrow peak suggests pitched sound, while unpitched sounds have a broad frequency spectrum.
